# How to rigorously prove that $S^1 \wedge S^1 \cong S^2$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

Defining $S^1\wedge S^1$ as $S^1\times S^1 \Big/ S^1\vee S^1$ and seeing the torus as a square with opposite sides identified, $S^1\vee S^1$ is just the boundary of the rectangle, so $S^1\wedge S^1$ would be the quotient of the disk $D^2$ with its boundary, that is
$$S^1\wedge S^1 = D^2/\partial D^2 \cong S^2$$
This explanation is okay to me, but I'd like to see a complete proof of this fact, and I don't know where to start. If it's possible I would like some hint on how to proceed rather than a whole answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's incomplete about the proof that you wrote?

Comment: @MoisheCohen It seemed intuitive to me but rather hand-wavy... I'm not sure

Comment: Which part are you unsure about? Can you prove that $D^2/\partial D \cong S^2$?

Comment: If you think that's hand-wavy just wait until you get to connected sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to make this feel more rigorous is to consider $S^1\times S^1$ as a CW-complex, and play with the quotient spaces to make everything come out right. **This won't be the nicest way to go about it**, but there will be more gritty details which can be illuminating. Since you don't want a complete answer, I'll give an outline with the details hidden in a spoiler.

**First, construct the $1$-skeleton. This is homeomorphic to $S^1\vee S^1$.**

> Let $X^0 = \{e_0\}$ and $D_1,D_2\cong\mathbb{D}^1$. Define attaching maps to be the constant maps $f_i:\partial D_i\to X^0$. For $Y_1:= X^0\bigsqcup D_i$, form the quotient space $X^1 = Y_1/(x\sim f_i(x))$ for $x\in\partial D_i$.

**Then attach a single disk  $D$ to create a complex homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$.**

> Now let $D\cong\mathbb{D}^2$ and define an attaching map $f:\partial D \to X^1$. *[For brevity's sake and my own, I'm going to omit the details of this particular attaching map. However, you should be able to construct this yourself.]* Then for $Y_2 := X^1\bigsqcup D$, we form the quotient space $X^2 = Y_2/(x\sim f(x))$ for $x\in\partial D$. Let $p$ be the quotient map $p:Y_2\to X^2$.

**Consider the quotient of the 2-skeleton by the 1-skeleton.**

> Now we consider the quotient space $X^2/X^1$ with quotient map $q$, and let $A$ denote the equivalence class $[X^1]$. To determine what this is, we follow the chain of quotient maps. For any $x\in(\partial D \cup X^1)$, the image $p(x)\in X^1$, and so $(q\circ p)(x)\in A$. Therefore $\partial D\mapsto A$. For any $y\in D^{\circ}$, by definition of our maps, $(q\circ p)(y) = y$.

**Note where $\partial D$ and $D^{\circ}$ are sent. Prove this space is $S^2$.**

> Then $r= (q\circ p)$ is a quotient map such that $r|_{D^{\circ}} = id_{D^{\circ}}$ and $r(\partial D)$ is a single point, say $b$. Thus we get a homeomorphism between $X^2/X^1$ and $D/\partial D$ by sending $A\mapsto b$ and acting as the identity everywhere else. Since $D/\partial D\cong S^2$, we're done.

*I'm not confident all the details here are correct, so feedback is welcome.*

Comment: Of course! Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

one can also use the universal property of quotients (and their uniqueness) to make this work in a slightly more rigorous way. This is a matter of taste, since I view your original argument as perfectly correct.

We see that $(S^1,\{pt\}) \cup (pt,S^1)$ indeed gives the boundary of $I^2$, where we view $T^2$ as the usual identification on the boundary of the unit square. Hence, we see that the composition of quotient maps $f:I^2 \to T^2 \to S^1 \wedge S^1$ necessarily makes the identification $q:I^2 \to I^2/\partial I^2$, so it must factor through $q$ as a map $\tilde{f}$.

However, note that outside of $\partial I^2$, $f$ is injective, since no identification occurs, and hence $\tilde{f}$ is in fact a bijection since quotients are also surjective. But now, a continuous bijection between a compact and Hausdorff space is necessarily a homeomorphism.